# How to switch different layout measure method onClick on map rotation

Tags: java, android, dictionary, rotation

i have this code that control the size of my layout. This is the default parameters on activity start:

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int w = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        final int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(w, h);
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

when i click on a button that active map rotation, i need the parameters change like so:

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


            int w = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
            int sizeSpec;
        if (w > h) {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (w * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (h * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(sizeSpec, sizeSpec);
        }



        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

and when i click to a button that stop map rotation, i need the parameters back to default.

How can i do this?
Thank you

I would like to use this buttons to start and stop switch different layout measure

```
ImageButton compass = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.compass);
compass.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_click_gps);
compass.setEnabled(true);

compass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            activeSensorAndMapRotation();
        }
    });



ImageButton compassNo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.compass_no);
compassNo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.action_click);
compassNo.setEnabled(true);

compassNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sensorAndMapRotationNo();

        }
    });
```

Comment: I am sure you meant java, not JavaScript

Comment: sorry, i correct that

Comment: I think you should add an if-else clause and a variable that shows if map rotation is enabled

Comment: i have try. but it start the rotation with the screen measure of the default parameters

Comment: I don't get it:) What is happening? What do you mean by default parameters?

Comment: default parameters means the measure of (code 1). i have try to create twoo boolean method, one start the activity with code 1, and the second, should change the measure and start the activity.but if i try, it start the rotation but with the previous measure

Comment: Do you need to save data temporarily, and reuse it during your app's lifecycle?

Comment: I believe that you don't need to re-measure your `View` for different rotation angles, but instead use `clipChildren="false"` in your parent `ViewGroup`

Comment: i would like to start and stop the rotation with a toggle button.